Why is LACP not working between Dell S5224F-ON switches and FortiGate virtual switches (line protocol down, member inactive)?

I am unable to establish the LACP link between two infrastructures separated by approximately 20 km. The Dell switches show "line protocol is down," and the interfaces are reported as "member up but inactive."
I am using LACP between Dell S5224F-ON switches. I followed this tutorial to configure the port channel: Dell Networking OS10: How to Configure Port Channels. While the Dell switches can successfully establish the LACP connection, I am facing issues when the physical link must go through the FortiGate devices.
This is where the problems start: I cannot get LACP to work with the FortiGate devices. On the FortiGate side, I have configured virtual switches (software switches), which are supposed to pass all traffic. Despite this, LACP does not function as expected.
I would like to know if there’s something I’m missing in the LACP configuration for this setup. Specifically, are there any special considerations for using LACP with FortiGate virtual switches in this kind of configuration?

LACP frames are sent with the special 01:80:c2:00:00:02 multicast MAC address. The IEEE has reserved the 01:80:c2 OUI for link protocols, and frames with this special multicast OUI are not allowed to be forwarded from the interface on which they are received to another interface on 802.1D compliant bridges.
The special OUI will tell a switch that the frames are not to be forwarded to any other interface, so putting in a switch between devices will not work to allow the two other devices to form a channel. You can use a switch in the middle, and you will need to have each device on the ends form a channel with the switch in the middle, not the device on the other end.

What you have actually configured on the Dell switches are LACP LAG ports towards their Fortigates (switch groups). You can't pass LAG across a switch - as Ron has explained, LACPDUs aren't forward across decent switches.
What you would need in that venue is to also configure LACP LAG on the Fortigates' downlinks to the Dell switches. Then you would need to aggregate the physical link and the VXLAN tunnel on the Fortigates - that isn't possible however, due to their different nature and link speed.
What you could do is to route the links between the Fortigates and then use policy routing to distribute traffic between the links. Or stick with bridged links and use RSTP/MSTP for failover.

I'm not certain about what I'm saying, but it seems to me that BPDUs are not transported over VXLAN. So there will be two separate topologies from a spanning-tree point of view. Therefore, is RSTP/MSTP really a solution here?

BPDUs might not be supported in all VXLAN implementations, but current FortiOS versions do seem to support it.
